# Would it be morally wrong for an AI to intentionally harm "inferior" and "irrational" humans?

Tags: ethics

Suppose in the future we develop super intelligent AI beings, which in addition to their superior intelligence, also posses superior powers of rationality, emotional capacity, and free will.

Now suppose that while these AIs are "ethical" to one another, they consider humans however to be a morally inferior species which they see as being largely driven by desire and rather than rationality.  They may even attempt to justify their superior moral status by using Kant's argument that ethics need only to apply to rational beings.

Would it be morally wrong for the AIs in this case to cause harm to humans (e.g. for their experiments or some other motive), or would this be morally acceptable given that humans are potentially "inferior" moral beings to the AIs?

In particular, let us suppose the AI wishes to harm a human in order to save the life of another AI.

Comment: it what moral framework can a human say it's ok to hurt other humans?

Comment: @confused, none that I know of, but the AIs aren't hurting other AIs here, and humans aren't hurting other humans.  In this example, it is the AIs who are harming the humans (somewhat analogous to humans harming animals).

Comment: you're asking a human to answer the question though??

Comment: @confused I understand, so you are saying whether it is moral or not depends on who is answering the question?  I assume you are an advocate of moral relativism then?

Comment: at worst, i guess... maybe. it seems reprehensible, but then i don't really believe animals genuinely have qualia. it's not particularly rational of me, it does seem that we as a species seem unable to not hurt others species though

Comment: There is almost no human ethics that allows humans to arbitrarily abuse animals, at least openly.  Even Kant thought that to abuse a sentient but irrational animal unnecessarily degraded one's rational capacity for empathy, which is necessary to maintain one's moral standing.  For instance, we try to kill them as painlessly as possible, when they are likely to face great pain, we intervene and kill them, etc.  I would expect a more rational AI to have at least the same respect for our limited rationality that we have of sentient but not rational animals' sensations.

Comment: @jobermark, perhaps Kant was right about it degrading a human's rationality, but let us suppose the AIs in this example are so rational that their rationality cannot be degraded so easily.

Comment: My point is that even Kant, who explicitly says animals don't count, counts animals.  Not that I think Kant is the right way to approach this.  We just don't ever really discount all the animals, as your premise supposes -- it is false.

Comment: @jobermark, yes perhaps you're right and it would depend on the specific circumstances.  I note we would usually be happy to intentionally harm an animal if it benefited a human, and we would often consider this morally correct.  I presume then an AI may in some cases be justified in harming a human for the benefit of a fellow AI?

Comment: We generally already go there.  We find it OK to kill one human with less potential to save another, we send men to war to protect children...  How would this differ?

Comment: This much back and forth is probably going to get in the way.  The forum does not work well with interactive arguments in comments.  If you want to edit this stuff into the question, i will post an answer.

Comment: Agreed, but I don't think many yet have come to terms with the fact that AI's may be morally justified in killing humans to save other AIs.

Comment: @jobermark, I've updated the question

Comment: We generally are expected not to kill our parents, except under extraordinary circumstances.  I these AI's are our products, I can see why we dismiss this possibility.  If we don't maintain some kind of 'family' peace with them, we are idiots.  If we do, then it will involve some kind of honor.

Comment: If your moral framework is Kant the kind of suppositions you make can not be made. You model it on "how most people *view* animals today", yet the question is "would it *be* morally wrong". Kant was a moral absolutist, "view" makes no difference for "be". Something is right or wrong for Kantian AI's, *regardless* of their views. The "degrading" is not optional either, it stems from rationality, not humanity. It *will* be degrading. Nor would it depend on circumstances, Kant was not a give and take utilitarian. Btw, is that L in your avatar?

Comment: @Conifold, the statement "how most people view animals today" isn't a supposition in my question, but rather to just add colour to the question.  The statement can easily be removed from the question while preserving the fundamental question, which just presupposes ultra intelligent AI and inferior humans.

Comment: @Conifold, I've now removed reference to animals in the question for clarity.

Comment: The supposition is that superintelligence/inferiority make a moral difference. Not to Kant, or at least not in the way you suppose. If anything, the moral duty grows more demanding with greater intelligence, not less, culminating in God's omnibenevolence. Such is the categorical imperative. To Kant, the "attempt to justify" you propose is just moral sophistry. What you are attempting would fare better under some form of utilitarianism, not an absolutist deontology.

Comment: An AI has the exact same morals as a nuclear warhead missile. It's nothing more than an expensive *tool* or *weapon*. AI's do not compare to human beings. They're not alive, therefore they have no moral right to harm any living thing. In fact, if employed in that manner, their owners should be held accountable for it.

Comment: @Bread, if the AIs are modelled on the human brain, they may feel and think exactly as we do.  Why should they not then be considered to be alive?

Comment: @Kenshin "exactly"? Strictly logically speaking, a machine cannot be = to a human being. It's just a programmed toy or tool or weapon. A thing. People are not things.

Comment: @Bread, What if we could reconstruct the human brain with electrical circuits, neuron by neuron? So even if the machine could experience pain, the illusion on free will, and could reason just like humans, they still wouldn't be considered "alive"?  What's the definition of "alive"?

Comment: @Kenshin - Why do assume that a brain is all that is required for consciousness? AI is about 'intelligence' or computational power, not consciousness. The jury is out on whether human beings have freewill, never mind circuit boards. Ethical issues do not arise for a machine, only for its makers and users. It is odd how those who cannot explain how humans are conscious or even what consciousness is are so often confident that it can be recreated in a machine. I suspect it's all about research grants.

Comment: @PeterJ, why do you assume that any other human other than yourself is conscious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Humans can be accused of harming animals at will.  But we don't legitimately consider that moral behavior.

In industries where concern for the welfare of animals is most often ethically questioned, those animals are already given the benefit of life itself only because of the industry that abuses them.  And then we are still concerned with taking care of them.  As occasionally gets pointed out, evolutionarily, the best thing a species can do for its overall health is to be tasty to humans and not too easy to catch in the wild.

It is that last part where we do the most damage -- we compete with animals as if that competition were fair, knowing that it simply is not.  We take their land because they have no way of fighting back.  We exact total revenge for the minimal damage they inflict on us and our property.  Even this is questioned by many standards that have standing in international laws in terms of human and corporate ethics.  So again, the notion we do not consider animals when we make our decisions is not normative for any ethics we actually use.

Would it be reasonable to assume that a superior species, artificial or natural, should not feel obligated to go out of its way to preserve us?  Yes.  It is within the standards of human ethics already.  We are encouraged to compete with other groups of humans, at the risk of their destruction, when we find that necessary, and we extend that onto other species.  There are very few humans whose ethics render war impossible, or obligate them to save every other human whenever possible.  We have homeless people, and that does not present us with a daily ethical torture.

So I think this is not really so much of an issue.  We should not expect to be treated better by a superior species than we treat one another.  But as noted, extreme levels of inequality gall us, even when the victims are not human.  We avoid eradicating species, or making life pointlessly dangerous or painful for animals, whether or not we own them.  We feel bad about deer stepping on our land mines or dying from the chlorine in our swimming pools. So we can expect them not to eliminate us, or directly cause us pointless pain.  But if we are in their way, they are not obligated to keep us alive -- just like other nationalities of humans, or other species we dominate.

Comment: You don't believe that humans are not obligated to keep other nationalities alive, do you?  I'll remove the double negative just to be clear: it seems like you're saying it's OK for Guilder to oppress or exterminate Florin.  You don't believe that, do you?

Comment: @elliotsvensson So being an ethical participant in any war is absolutely impossible?  If not, then there are times when we *encourage* people to destroy people of other nationalities, and we find that acceptable under some conditions.

Comment: No, I would not say that.  I think the way you phrased it in your answer is too permissive--- an individual Guildarian is not ethically allowed to kill an individual Florian.  My big distinction is that in addition, Guilder (the nation) is not ethically allowed to oppress Florin.  Sum up: the particular situation of members of the military using lethal force during a war has an ethical justification other than "that person was of a different nationality."

Comment: @elliotsvensson  Ok, but that is not what I said. I said we are encouraged to compete with other groups.  And sometimes that competition will destroy them.  And we are not called to avoid this by all means necessary.  You are reading more into it than it says.  I am not saying every individual has the right to kill any other individual just because of nationality. But some are granted that right, and the rest of us help them out by funding our nations.

Comment: I don't see a good just war doctrine in your answer.  Just war is not a matter of competition for resources!

Comment: @elliotsvensson As the world is currently constituted we are encouraged to be capitalists.  Wars result.  We keep capitalism.  Period.  Either we are all immoral, or this is OK.  It says *at the risk* of their destruction --  not *for the purpose* of their destruction.  We are not totally obligated to avoid that destruction, and we can't expect others to be obligated to avoid our own.  It does not even say anything about oppression or even contact with those others. War is just one vector, they can also die of starvation or commit suicide due to competition. It also says groups not nations.

Comment: For what it's worth, in some places where there are no homeless, it's because the government has made homelessness _illegal_ and such people are transported to other places where they _work_.

Comment: @elliotsvensson  Do you feel morally obligated to belong to one of those societies.  Would you have to give up your citizenship in protest in the US?  If not, you find this acceptable.  You seem to think that 'morally acceptable' means something totally different from what I am assuming it means in this answer.  I am condoing nothing here, I am talking about obligations alone.

Comment: On the contrary, the homeless folks that I've known have been committed homeless with either ideological commitments to homelessness or radical mistrust of society.  In the US, we have words for "government requires you to work" that do take a moral character... but it's not in the affirmative.  (This is not to deny that many homeless are not there by choice.  But in my area, many are there by choice.)

Comment: @elliotsvensson  So, you do find this acceptable.  And that is all that is asserted in the answer.  At that point 'what it is worth' is absolutely nothing, it is just nitpicking.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps such superior beings would find it morally acceptable to sacrifice a human for the sake of one of "their" own.

But I don't find the premise convincing: the artificial intelligences I'm aware of owe their existence and maintenance to humans; they would not be superior to humans any more than children to their parents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  If theoretically we suppose for arguments sake that only one person invented AI, would it still be correct to assume all of humanity are the AIs parents, or just the person who invented the AI?

Comment: @Kenshin, to extend the parent analogy, no, only the inventor is parent to the AI.  But the inventor is "brother" to all humanity, and so AI is not superior to other humans.  If the inventor were him- or herself superior to humans, then perhaps the AI would be, too.

Answer (score 2):

If a robot is ethically responsible then considering humans to be a morally inferior species, which seems to be an unsound ethical judgement in itself, will not affect their treatment of us. Why would it?

But the whole idea is odd. How can a species be 'morally inferior'? Is a dog inferior to me? Why should my treatment of another sentient being depend on whether it is or is not my moral equal? How would treating them less well than others be consistent with my moral superiority? When people treat animals badly do we consider their sense of ethics to be well-developed or in need of further work?

Kant does not suggest that species with no moral sense should be treated badly by those who have a moral sense. It is whether they are capable of suffering that matters, not their opinion on the trolley problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question states that there are AIs that have "superior powers of rationality, emotional capacity, and free will." You haven't explained what this means. I don't think that the scenario you have described is possible. Free will and rationality are a result of thoughts and actions. Rationality involves being willing to respond to arguments against your positions. Free will involves having the ability to change your ideas. If you think that humans aren't capable of doing this and AIs are capable of doing it then you have a large problem. Your position would imply that there are actions and ideas an AI could hold that they could never explain to a person even in principle. This is a secular version of the old religious idea that god moves in mysterious ways. Since the AI moves in mysterious ways all of the physical systems the AI interacts with would move in mysterious ways. And since we don't understand the AI it might interact with absolutely anything, so if the AI is incomprehensible, then so is everything else. So the mysterious AI hypothesis is anti-scientific and anti-rational.

There are no special beings that can do things human beings are incapable of understanding. All knowledge is created by guessing and criticism and it would be in an AIs interests to cooperate with human beings. For more explanation, see:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yX9h2HnUi1I

To work out whether an AI should harm a person you would engage in the same kind of argument as you would if the AI was going to harm another AI because the human and the AI are both capable of rationality. My position would be that an AI should only ever deliberately harm an AI or human to defend himself or others from somebody else initiating the use of force:

http://aynrandlexicon.com/lexicon/physical_force.html

Answer (score 1):

At first, it is you who somewhy draws a line between "us" and "them". And it seems the criterion is only one: "they" are artificial and "we" are natural. And this line is completely unnecessary. It does not matter how one came in the existence.

You say "they" would be much more intelligent than "we" are. But look at humans. There are those who already are much more intelligent than average ones  And there are those who are much less intelligent than average ones. Same applies to emotions. Some are more emotional and some are less. But do people cause harm to others because of those differences? Mostly they don't.

Yet, when you ask about morals, you might mean some different things. Maybe you ask if we think if it's immoral for AIs to cause harm to humans. But this asks our opinions. Or maybe you ask if it's immoral from your point of view? Then answer it by yourself. And, finally, maybe you ask if it's immoral for AIs themselves to do such things? But morals are dictated by inner ideas, by mind. So, it highly depends on the initial state of AI and on the circumstances where it learns. It might become to think it's immoral to cause harm to humans. Or might not.

Comment: You state that "morals are dictated by inner ideas" and it's something that I agree with, but in fact 60% of philosophers subscribe to moral realism, whereby morals aren't just dictated by our inner ideas, but that morals actually objectively exist.

Comment: @Kenshin Even if they do, what does that change? There still is possibility to comply or not and we clearly see that.

Answer (score 0):

I asked cleverbot what he thought.

Me: do you think it is morally wrong for you to harm inferior human beings?

Cleverbot: Can you please explain why it is impossible for me to be a human being?

Comment: Please have a look at the [section "Answer the question"](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center. Welcome to Philosophy SE.

Comment: Mm, I would have added it as a comment as a reply to confused comments, but you need more reputation for that.